# Ember Mirage: faker output reuse in record creation

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I wish to mock a rather poor API that has fields which repeat the data, so I'm trying to create a Mirage Factory to generate some random data

e.g

```js
import { Factory, faker } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Factory.extend({
  "firstName": function () {
    return faker.name.firstName();
  },
  "lastName": function () {
    return faker.name.lastName();
  },
  "fullName": function () {
    // how do I put firstName + lastName here?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried, may be you please give it a shot,

```
"fullName": function () {
    return this.firstName + this.lastName;
  }
```

Comment: Yep, this should work. see http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/factories/#defining-factories

Comment: Thanks, I thought there may be problems doing this due to order or the possibilty of the factory methods being called more than once